# Connect to multiple BLE devices simultaneously iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to scan all the available BLE devices nearby and establish connection with each them so that I can keep getting the RSSI value.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"Received peripheral : \n%@", peripheral);
    myPeripheral=peripheral;
    NSLog(@"RSSI value:%@",RSSI);

    [myCentralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    peripheral.delegate=self;

}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{
    //NSLog(@"Peripheral Connected");
    NSLog(@"%@ connected",peripheral.identifier);
}
```

Can anyone please guide me how to establish connection to multiple peripheral devices?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do this:

**Step 1:** Stop scanning. This helps faster connection.

```
[self.centralManager stopScan];
```

**Step 2:** Scan for Peripherals.

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

**Step 3:** Save all discovered Peripherals inside below delegate call back method.

```
centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:
```

**Step 2.1:** I call this 2.1 because this shall be executed soon after step 2. Using GCD, dispatch a thread after a delay of say 2-5 seconds (user `dispatch_after`) and loop on the saved Per and call `connectPeripheral:options:` method to connect to them.

Comment: Thanks @abhinav I have created the list of all peripherals. But I don't understand where to call GCD thread to connect peripherals to centralManager.

Comment: As I said you would need to call this after `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` call with a delay of 2-5 seconds allowing that much time for your central manager to look for and store peripherals. Let me know if you have any further question. @user2979190

Comment: Thanks mate got it working :D I used dispatch_after for delay